# Seamless Sign On - Single Sign On

Tags: single-sign-on, identity, refresh-token

I am using OpenID protocol and my need is to make the access to Salesforce seamless, after the user is authenticated by the Identity Provider.

- My Identity Provider is a internal LDAP managed by keycloak
- Once the user is authenticated on it (*regardless if was to access first Salesforce or other internal system*) all the links inside salesforce, or inside the internal system, should be acessible. Without asking to log in, or authrorize again.

How can this be accomplished?

With the current SSO implementation the user is taken to the log in page if he attempts to access a internal salesforce link. He does not need to enter the credentials again, just authorize, if he had been already previously athenticated by the IDP through other internal system.

If the authenticates on the IDP first through salesforce, everything works fine. The links does not redirect to the log in page.

So, how to make all system seamless after only one authentication on the IDP, regardless the system who issued the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to go to My Domain and make sure the only authentication method checked is your Single Sign On configuration, and that login is unchecked.  This will force Salesforce to try authenticating users with that SSO configuration rather than asking them to choose it at the login screen when they access internal Salesforce links using your domain.

Comment: After I set the My Domain to allow login only through SSO, I'm not prompt to authorize again if I had been previously authenticated by another internal system that uses the same IDP.

This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

That's a feature of the IdP, not Salesforce. You will need to configure the IdP to control how sessions are authenticated. For example, in our org, the IdP will reauthenticate automatically within about an hour of the first login, or automatically if Kerberos/NTLM authentication is detected (e.g. Internet Explorer). Salesforce itself should automatically redirect if you use the correct My Domain name (e.g. https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/someurl) instead of a generic URL (e.g. https://login.salesforce.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Since Salesforce is Service Provider so you need to setup two things:

1. My domain at Salesforce
2. Single sign on setup at Salesforce